# How to display a module only on the homepage?

Tags: html, css, prestashop

The "block_categories" module is displayed on several pages, even though I want it to be displayed only on the homepage. For example, if I click the "checkout" button, you'll notice that the "block_categories" module was made public as well, and I don't want that. Do you know how I can fix this?

http://i61.tinypic.com/2462pv6.png

Answer (score 1):

In the admin you should go to 'Modules / Positions'.
Then select 'Category block', in the dropdown.
Search 'Left column blocks' and click on the edit button of the 'Category block' inside.
Add every page in exceptions except for 'index'.

Then search 'Pages header' and do the same thing as with 'Left column blocks' (it is to avoid to load the css of the module when not necessary).

Answer (score -1):

You must add class to tag `body` or `html` on homepage and then you can show/hide any element only on this page

```
 #sidebar{displau:none;}
.homepage #sidebar{display:block;}
```

Comment: This is a VERY bad approach in prestashop. And i seriously hope nobody ever does that.